# Why does this script only work when run directly from powershell but not from another script

Tags: powershell, scoping, strict

I am deploying a Logic App that triggers on event grid. After deployment I need to authenticate the API connection. I found this script https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth and it works fine. But only if I run it manually from Powershell. But I want to call that script from another script, from the one that deploys the Logic App, after the New-AzResourceGroupDeployment command.

Doing that does not work. I get the error:

```
The variable '$Scope' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\location\LogicAppConnectionAuth.ps1:16 char:113
+ ... Browser -Property @{Width=580;Height=780;Url=($url -f ($Scope -join " ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Scope:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

What is that $scope variable? It is not defined in the script, still it exists when run separately, but not when I run the script from another script.

Comment: Maybe it's a copy-paste error, as [one version of OAuth](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MVP/0.0.1.0/Content/Private%5CGet-MVPOAuthAutorizationCode.ps1) script uses that specific variable. As why it doesn't work via another a script, maybe the latter will use [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6) (which should be the default setting anyway.)

Comment: The script where I run it from does have Set-StrictMode -Version 3. Looks like removing that makes it work. 

Ok, maybe the $scope is an error then, because it is not set anywhere, neither is it read anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [you've discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54651762/45375), in your specific case the problem was a normally benign bug that surfaced due to the *caller* enabling strict mode. However, the problem is a fundamental one, as discussed below.

---

The underlying problem is that, as of v6.2, **PowerShell's strict mode is *dynamically* scoped, not lexically**.

This means that using **`Set-StrictMode` doesn't just affect the function or script in which it is called**, but also **other functions and scripts called *from* that function or script** that live **in the same *scope domain***, that is, if both the caller and callee are either defined *outside* of a module or defined in the *same* module.

In other words: **A script or function may *unwittingly inherit* a strict-mode setting and may *break***, if it wasn't designed for that mode.

For instance, the callee may assume that the strict mode is at its default, `-Off`, and rely on (loosely) testing the non-existence of a variable `$var` with `if (-not $var)`, for instance. If a caller in the same scope domain has `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` or higher set, the callee will break.

**Workarounds**:

- **If *you* control the script or function being invoked**:

  - **Explicitly call `Set-StrictMode` at the start of your script or function** with the mode that your code is designed for.

    - Given the behavior described, **it is worth doing that *as a matter of habit* in non-module scripts and functions**.
  - Note: Bear in mind that this mode is then also in effect for scripts/functions in the same scope domain called from within the script or function at hand, as well as scripts/functions *they* call. (By contrast, code *higher* up the call stack is not affected).
- **Otherwise**:

  - ***Temporarily disable* strict mode** in order to call a script or function that expects strict mode to be off (or at a lower version):

    ```
    # Temporarily turn strict mode off.
    Set-StrictMode -Off

    # Call the script or function that breaks with (a higher) strict mode in effect
    ...

    # Re-enable strict mode for your code.
    # Note that there's no way to *get* (and save for later restoring)
    # the specific mode in effect.
    Set-StrictMode -Version <n>
    ```

**Future outlook**:

[This RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/issues/7) suggests introducing a *lexically* scoped strict mode to avoid the problems with the current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the $scope variable is there by some copy-paste error. It is not declared, set or read anywhere. Running the calling script in StrictMode 3 is what causes the error. Removing that, removes the error but that isn't really a solution.

I posted an issue to the github repo and fixed my own solution by just declaring the $scope variable as an empty string.